# How to programmatically edit field settings of a content type

Tags: entities, 9

My ultimate goal is to use a drush command to change the allowed paragraphs in a paragraph entity reference field for various content types.
I'm able to load the field entity and see the settings I need to change.

```
$field_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'my_custom_content_type');
$field_definitions['two_column_accordion']['enabled'] = TRUE;
```

However I'm not sure how to actually change the settings and save it for the content type. getFieldDefinitions returns an array containing the information I need to change but what it returns isn't by reference so I'm not sure how I can save anything.

How can I edit the settings of an entity reference field programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to perform the edit like so

```
$field_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'custom_content_type');
      if(isset($field_definitions['field_content'])){
          $current_settings = $field_definitions['field_content']->get('settings');
          $current_settings['handler_settings']['target_bundles_drag_drop']['two_column_accordion']['enabled'] = TRUE;
          $field_definitions['field_content']->set('settings', $current_settings);
          $field_definitions['field_content']->save();
      }
```

Once I realized that $field_definitions['field_name'] was a [FieldConfig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21src%21Entity%21FieldConfig.php/class/FieldConfig/9.0.x) object I was able to see that the 'get', 'set', and 'save' methods were what I needed.